# Force re-evaluation of live-filtered IListDataSource

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs

I'm using a live-filtered projection over a WinJS.Binding.List created using createFiltered().

The filter predicate operates on a string variable that is set by an event handler listening to Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onquerysubmitted.

How do I trigger a re-evaluation of the filtered projection when the search string changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the variable that your predicate filter is using to inspect items and then call `notifyReload()` on the source list. Here is a little code fragment to demonstrate:

```
    var mainList = new WinJS.Binding.List(["one", "two", "three"]);

    var filterString = "t";

    function filter(item) {
        var result = item.indexOf(filterString) > -1;
        console.log("Filter: " + item + " " + result);
        return result;
    };

    var filteredList = mainList.createFiltered(filter);

    filterString = "e";
    mainList.notifyReload();
```

When `notifyReload` is called, the predicate will be reapplied to regenerate the contents of the filtered list. In this fragment, the call to `console.log` will let you see how the filter is being reapplied.